# Questions around VivaGraph WebGL based rendering

Tags: javascript, graph, webgl, vivagraphjs

I have been using VivaGraphs for network analysis, but my knowledge is very rusty around JavaScript and concepts of SVG and WebGL in particular. I have been able to create nice networks using both SVG and WebGL and need a few pointers from you:

1. I feel WebGL is way faster than SVG when it comes to rendering large networks. I tried on a network with 80k edges and 20k nodes. Am I right in this assumption?
2. SVG is far easier to customize appearance of nodes and edges, WebGL is far too restrictive (or maybe my lack of knowledge). As in do you believe SVG gives me far more flexibility in customization?
3. One thing I noticed is that I need to pause my graph after some time otherwise the clusters in my graph keep on drifting. Anyway I can restrict my graph coordinates so that it never goes out of my screen size?
4. One major issue with WebGL I faced was that when I paused the rendered, none of my code worked (like events for node hover, click etc). But the moment I resumed it, it worked. This is not the case in SVG. My Hover,click functions on nodes work even if renderer is paused. This is a big showstopper in my case. Do you think there is a way to counter this?

Answer (score 1):

Please [open an issue](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/issues) on GitHub repository or share a link with broken webgl inputs - I'll be happy to take a look and fix a problem.

In terms of your intuition, yes, webgl is much faster, yet requires more effort to work with.